# Why is their total variance explained for factor analysis higher than mine?

Tags: variance, pca

I have conducted a study assessing the factor structure of a questionnaire.  I have extracted a five factor solution that explains 30% of the total variance in item responses.

Previous research has conducted a very similar study with a five-factor solution that accounts for 45% of the variance - a lot more than mine!

Why does their model account for more of the variance than mine?  We have similar sample sizes (n=294 and n=300), my sample was more homogeneous (smaller standard deviation of ages) and I had two reliable factors while they only had one.

What factors affect the total variance explained?  Does anyone have an idea why their's is greater?

Comment: Without links to the studies in question, it is difficult to answer this question. However, the total variance explained is a sample statistic. You need confidence intervals to compare sample means, and in a similar way, you would need some measure of uncertainty to go with the estimates of variance-explained in order to compare them.